# How can I check what process is launched without refreshing all running processes

Tags: android

I have written android app which kills background processes. My app looks for running processes lets say if browser opens it will close and kill it. Now it will check again this after some delay.
The thing annoying me is that I have to refresh it again and again, I need to catch any app launched on phone or something else and see whether lets say 'is a browser' then close and kill it.

Any efficient method to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a broadcast receiver, this sits and waits for the system to send it a prompt. Standard actions at the moment are:

> Standard Broadcast Actions
>
> These are the current standard actions that Intent defines for receiving broadcasts (usually through registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) or a  tag in a manifest).
>
> ACTION_TIME_TICK
>
> ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
>
> ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
>
> ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
>
> ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
>
> ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED
>
> ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
>
> ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED
>
> ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
>
> ACTION_UID_REMOVED
>
> ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
>
> ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
>
> ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED
>
> ACTION_SHUTDOWN

There is also:
[ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH)

but I think this is only sent to the Package that start's the app. (and is API 12)

So yeah instead of polling us a Listener.

Take a look at [ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED)

> Broadcast Action: The user has restarted a package, and all of its processes have been killed. All runtime state associated with it (processes, alarms, notifications, etc) should be removed.

[Example Implementation](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-11.html)

Perhaps you can use this?

Comment: thnx Blundell, I will implement it and let u knw

Answer (score 0):

Another function may be useful to you, [getRecentTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29).